# How to display a custom content type widget in the dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, jet-engine

I created a site with a Custom Content Type (Jet Engine) "Contact form" that is added from the front page. I need to display a dashboard widget (box) for this CCT in order to avoid having to enter to the CCT menu and checking if there is any new entry.

I can't find any related documentation for what I am trying to do. But I found how to add a new box into the dashboard from functions.php:

```php
// Widget Contact Form
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'custom_widget_contact_form' );

function custom_widget_contact_form() {
    if ( current_user_can ( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        wp_add_dashboard_widget ( 
            'custom_contact_form_widget', 
            'Formularios de Contacto', 
            'custom_dashboard_contact_form'
        );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists ( 'custom_dashboard_contact_form' ) ) {
    function custom_dashboard_contact_form() {
        ?>
            A shortcode? Pure PHP? what...
        <?php
    }
}
```

I don't know what to enter there. But I guess this is how I should start...